# How to Display a DataGrid with Insert Mode without any pre-filled data?

Tags: asp.net

How to display the datagrid in insert mode without any data in it.

The GridView is empty and contains only one header.

I want to insert the data in the GridView when the application is running.

Comment: What exactly is the intention of using the Grid? When you say no database, do you mean that you want to use an in-memory data store? If not, then are you looking for some sort of free-form data entry, like a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is using an empty Binding Source to a List which would enable you to add new Rows.

Check out some samples of how to use the [Binding Source here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at these 2 examples:

- [Insert rows with a GridView](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626064420/http://blog.binaryocean.com:80/2006/01/05/InsertRowsWithAGridView.aspx)
- [Adding Insert Capabilities to the GridView](https://web.archive.org/web/20200719080658/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/casualjim/archive/2006/05/04/77151.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the datagrid will be rendered if its data source is empty. To work around this problem you can give it a data source with only one item that is regarded as empty (for example a data table with one row where all columns have empty values). You can then check for this special case in your program logic.